# Creating new category columns with corresponding values from a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I'm trying to create a SELECT statement where the values under "category" and "category2" column will become actual columns and show the corresponding "url" and "url2" under them.

Basically I have the following table:

```
      names       |    category    |            url            |   category2  |         url2             
------------------+----------------+---------------------------+--------------+------------------------------
  Jennifer        | Homepage       | http://www.example1.com   |              | 
  Jacob           | Github         | http://www.github.com     |              |  
  Tom             | Homepage       | http://www.example2.com   |    Github    | http://www.github2.com
  Nal             | Facebook Page  | http://www.facebook.com   |              | 
  Matt            | Homepage       | http://www.example3.com   |              |
  Daniel          |                |                           |    Homepage  | http://www.example4.com
  Sarah           |                |                           |    Other     | http://www.other_example.com
```

...and I want the end result to look like this:

```
         names     |        Homepage          |         Github         |     Facebook Page       |        Other           
-------------------+--------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------
    Jennifer       | http://www.example1.com  |                        |                         |
    Jacob          |                          | http://www.github.com  |                         |
    Tom            | http://www.example2.com  | http://www.github2.com |                         |
    Nal            |                          |                        | http://www.facebook.com |
    Matt           | http://www.example3.com  |                        |                         |
    Daniel         | http://www.example4.com  |                        |                         | 
    Sarah          |                          |                        |                         | http://www.other_example.com
```

Any ideas? I don't know which options to even look for?
I'm using PostgreSQL.

[Demo v3](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wpmyVpcWVCmAoLhAX4iuXa/3)

Comment: Are there only these 3 categories?

Comment: Nope, there are more, I just trimmed them here for simplicity. I'll figure out how to add them once I see how it's done for these 3

Comment: This is better done in the application. SQL is not really suited for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these 3 categories you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select
  names,
  max(case category when 'Homepage' then url end) Homepage,
  max(case category when 'Github' then url end) GitHub,
  max(case category when 'Facebook Page' then url end) "Facebook Page"
from tablename
group by names
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wpmyVpcWVCmAoLhAX4iuXa/1).
Results:

```
| names    | homepage                 | github                | Facebook Page            |
| -------- | ------------------------ | --------------------- | ------------------------ |
| Jennifer | http://www.example1.com  |                       |                          |
| Tom      | http://www.example2.com  |                       |                          |
| Jacob    |                          | http://www.github.com |                          |
| Nal      |                          |                       | https://www.facebook.com |
| Matt     | https://www.example3.com |                       |                          |
```

**Edit**

```
select
  t.names,
  max(case t.category when 'Homepage' then t.url end) Homepage,
  max(case t.category when 'Github' then t.url end) GitHub,
  max(case t.category when 'Facebook Page' then t.url end) "Facebook Page",
  max(case t.category when 'Other' then t.url end) Other
from (
  select names, category, url from tablename
  union all
  select names, category2, url2 from tablename
) t     
group by t.names
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wpmyVpcWVCmAoLhAX4iuXa/4).
Results:

```
| names    | homepage                | github                 | Facebook Page           | other                        |
| -------- | ----------------------- | ---------------------- | ----------------------- | ---------------------------- |
| Jennifer | http://www.example1.com |                        |                         |                              |
| Sarah    |                         |                        |                         | http://www.other_example.com |
| Tom      | http://www.example2.com | http://www.github2.com |                         |                              |
| Jacob    |                         | http://www.github.com  |                         |                              |
| Nal      |                         |                        | http://www.facebook.com |                              |
| Daniel   | http://www.example4.com |                        |                         |                              |
| Matt     | http://www.example3.com |                        |                         |                              |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly what I needed. Unfortunately I did not show the whole picture as I thought I could figure it out.
There's another set of category and url that I'd like to nicely organize in my results list. I edited my original post to reflect this and added these values into the Demo V3 link in my post.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate your help!